# Disable device admin apps functionality completely

Tags: samsung, device-administrator

Every time I activate Google Play Services and reboot my phone (Galaxy A50, Android 9), Google Play Services gets automatically added to Device admin apps. It prevents also Google Play Services from deactivating on the Apps page. Each time I have to remove it from Device admin apps.

Honestly to say I don't like Device admin apps functionality at all and want it vanish from my phone so that no application could be added there even if it eagerly wants to.

Is it possible to remove Device admin apps functionality at all?

Comment: If you don't want to have Google Play Services with device admin capabilities do not install them. There are projects aiming in providing a replacement for Play Services, I don't know how good they are as I don't use them.